# How to Extract pages from a PDF using IText 7?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I trying to use the `iText7` library to extract some pages from a `PDF` file to create a new one.

```c#
    static void Splitter()
        {
        string file = @"C:\Users\Standard\Downloads\Merged\CK 2002989 $29,514.42 02.12.20.pdf";
        string range = "1, 4, 8";
        var pdfDocumentInvoiceNumber = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file));
        var split = new PdfSplitter(pdfDocumentInvoiceNumber);
        var result = split.ExtractPageRange(new PageRange(range));
        var numberOfPagesPdfDocumentInvoiceNumber = result.GetNumberOfPages();
        String toFile = @"C:\Users\Standard\Downloads\Result\Extracted.pdf";
        var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(toFile);
        var pdfDocumentInvoiceMergeResult = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPagesPdfDocumentInvoiceNumber; i++) 
            { 
            var pdfPage = result.GetPage(i).CopyTo(pdfDocumentInvoiceMergeResult);
            pdfDocumentInvoiceMergeResult.AddPage(pdfPage);
            }
        }
```

But when I attempt to use `CopyTo` method I get the error

```
iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'Cannot copy indirect object from the document that is being written.'
```

Comment: The problem is clear from the error message and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58434289/1729265) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815830/1729265): *This restriction that pages cannot be copied from documents written to is due to the iText architecture: When a document is written to, iText attempts to push this new content out into the `PdfWriter` output stream as soon as possible and then forget about it. This allows iText to easily produce large result PDFs without requiring a large amount of memory. The downside is the restriction you're confronted with.*

Comment: Another reason is that some structures in a document written to are not finalized before the document is closed, e.g. subset embedded fonts.

Comment: So, how can I even use the method ExtractPageRange() properly with that kind of limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the documents returned by the `PdfSplitter` methods, in particular by `ExtractPageRange`, are iText 7 documents *written to*, i.e. these `PdfDocument` instances have been instantiated with a `PdfWriter`.

Such documents are subject to certain restrictions, in particular that pages cannot be copied from them. For details on this read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58434289/1729265) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815830/1729265).

To make these result documents (and the whole `PdfSplitter` class with them) be of any value, therefore, you need a way to define where the `PdfWriter` objects of these documents write to. And there is a way, albeit not really an intuitive way: You have to overwrite the `GetNextPdfWriter` method of the `PdfSplitter` which originally looks like this:

```
/// <summary>This method is called when another split document is to be created.</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This method is called when another split document is to be created.
/// You can override this method and return your own
/// <see cref="iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter"/>
/// depending on your needs.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="documentPageRange">the page range of the original document to be included in the document being created now.
///     </param>
/// <returns>the PdfWriter instance for the document which is being created.</returns>
protected internal virtual PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange) {
    return new PdfWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
}
```

In a use case like yours in which you merely expect a single return document you eventually want to write to a file, you can do so like this:

```
class MySplitter : PdfSplitter
{
    public MySplitter(PdfDocument pdfDocument) : base(pdfDocument)
    {
    }

    protected override PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange)
    {
        String toFile = @"C:\Users\Standard\Downloads\Result\Extracted.pdf";
        return new PdfWriter(toFile);
    }
}
```

With the `PdfWriter` instantiation moved into that custom splitter your main code is reduced to

```
string file = @"C:\Users\Standard\Downloads\Merged\CK 2002989 $29,514.42 02.12.20.pdf";
string range = "1, 4, 8";
var pdfDocumentInvoiceNumber = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file));
var split = new MySplitter(pdfDocumentInvoiceNumber);
var result = split.ExtractPageRange(new PageRange(range));
result.Close();
```

In a use case like yours this admittedly looks weird, having to derive a custom class from the `PdfSplitter` merely to extract a few pages from a source PDF to a result PDF. Wouldn't an additional `PdfWriter` parameter to the `ExtractPageRange` have made it much easier?

Please be aware, though, that the main objective of the `PdfSplitter` class is to split documents into many parts using the `ExtractPageRanges` and `SplitBy...` methods, and in that situation you'd need to supply a larger, probably not exactly known number of `PdfWriters`... not easier at all!

Of course, a better solution probably would have been injecting some lambda expression or some other callback mechanism. For example:

```
class ImprovedSplitter : PdfSplitter
{
    private Func<PageRange, PdfWriter> nextWriter;
    public ImprovedSplitter(PdfDocument pdfDocument, Func<PageRange, PdfWriter> nextWriter) : base(pdfDocument)
    {
        this.nextWriter = nextWriter;
    }

    protected override PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange)
    {
        return nextWriter.Invoke(documentPageRange);
    }
}
```

you can use like this

```
string file = @"C:\Users\Standard\Downloads\Merged\CK 2002989 $29,514.42 02.12.20.pdf";
string range = "1, 4, 8";
var pdfDocumentInvoiceNumber = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file));
var split = new ImprovedSplitter(pdfDocumentInvoiceNumber, pageRange => new PdfWriter(@"C:\Users\Standard\Downloads\Result\Extracted.pdf"));
var result = split.ExtractPageRange(new PageRange(range));
result.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up overwriting the methods. But I still wonder what kind of use the default return of this method would have.

Comment: I'm not sure either.

Comment: What if Instead of extracting result pdf into file stream, if I want to use a memory stream. actually, I have the same requirement. bt only concern is I do not have permission to create a file On my production server.so I have to store them in a memory stream. So Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: @KaranShah in your `GetNextPdfWriter` override you can create such memory streams and store them in a collection property of your splitter class.  After splitting you can retrieve that collection from your splitter. Obvious collection choices would be either a list or a map based on the `PageRange` as corresponding key or value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is linked to `Splitter`; but the extraction can be done without it !

Following code replace your code without error's messages.

```vbnet
    Private Sub TestCopyTo()
        Dim pdfInput = New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(sPdfInputFile))
        Dim iPageRange As Integer() = {2, 4, 8}
        Dim iLastPage = iPageRange.Length - 1

        Using pdfNew = New PdfDocument(New PdfWriter("result.pdf"))
            For i = 0 To iLastPage
                Dim iPage = iPageRange(i)
                Dim oNewPage As PdfPage = pdfInput.GetPage(iPage).CopyTo(pdfNew)
                pdfNew.AddPage(oNewPage)
            Next i
            pdfNew.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

This is certainly more simple ... and do the job !

For your information, I have installed `iText7` version **7.2.5** using `Nuget` tool on `Visual Studio 2022` / `Windows 11`.