# How to create java File for each page from a signgle pdf document in iText 7 or above?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a single pdf file with 10 pages, I need to split into 10 files, how can I do it in iText?

I'm able to split the documents by page like below

```
List<PdfDocument> splitDocuments = new PdfSplitter(pdfDoc).splitByPageNumbers(1,2,3 ..10);
```

How Could I get get File object for each of the PdfDocument?

Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219452/1729265) discusses the analoguous topic for iText 7 for .NET.